# Ruby memory limit

Tags: ruby

Привет! В PHP есть такая конструкция: `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`
Как реализовать подобное в Ruby?

Comment: не надо ничего из PHP тащить в Ruby, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

И что эта опция конкретно должна делать, вылетать с NoMemoryError?
Если вы хотите, чтобы процесс завершался, когда съедает слишком много памяти, используйте мониторинговые инструменты, которые будут рестартовать пожирающие память процессы. С огранчением по процессору поможет справиться cpulimit.

Comment: Насколько я помню, плюс этой опции в php может быть то, что php не убивается а выкидывает ексепшен который можно отловить и среагировать на него скриптом. Но что имеет в виду автор...

Answer (score 1):

Управлять объёмом выделяемой памяти из кода простого приложения я не вижу смысла.
Если не стоит такой задачи конечно же. Выберите динамический сервер по вкусу (Unicorn, Puma, Thin) и пропишите в конфиге его поведение и размер памяти. [Гитхабовский бест практис](https://github.com/blog/519-unicorn-god).